# Is $0$ the Exponential Inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, inverse, inverse-function, hyperoperation

For a while, I've been wondering why this pattern seems to allude to the fact that $0$ is one of the inverses of exponentiation.

\begin{align}
& x \cdot -1 = -x & \text{Inverse of addition} \\
& x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x} & \text{Inverse of multiplication} \\
& ^{-1}x = n & \text{Inverse of exponentiation}
\end{align}
where $^{n}x$ indicates tetration on $x$. It seems that according to Wikipedia (not a great source, I know) $^{-1}x$ is equal to $0$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Negative_heights, which would imply that $n$ (the exponential inverse) should be $0$. At first this didn't make sense to me, but I quickly realized that this makes sense that it seems that any number and its inverse for some operation, when combined under that operation, produce that operation's identity, e.g. $x+-x=0$ and $x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1$. Assuming that $1$ is the exponential identity, it makes perfect sense that $0$ is the exponential inverse as $x^{0} = 1$.

Some things to note about this defintion of the exponential inverse is that  $0^x \ne 1$, but instead $1^x = 1$. I currently don't see how this is justified by this technique. Also, it doesn't seem that $0$ is tied to either of the exponential inverse *functions* in the same way $\frac{1}{x}$ is tied to division and $-x$ is tied to subtraction, though I would expect to be tied to the $n$th-root operation.

I'm sorry if my explanations are a bit vague. I am not very knowledgeable with hyperoperations and this area of math. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: For your note about $0^x \ne 1$, I think an important fact to note is that exponentiation, unlike addition and multiplication, is not commutative. $x^0 = 1$ (for $x \ne 0$, for $x=0$ it is ambiguous, and I'm sure there are many posts on this site about that case)

Comment: $a^b \neq b^a$, exponentiation is not commutative

Comment: $0$ is not so much the "exponential inverse" as much as it is the exponential **right-**inverse, which is distinct from a left-inverse and an inverse in general.  You have shown that it is not a left-inverse.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I am fairly sure that is the reason why there are two different exponential inverses, as this method works out the right inverses, but I'm still not sure as to why the left inverse is $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, okay. Thanks. I'll edit my comment to fit that definition of left and right inverses.